# Chart.js (v. 2.4) - How to fix pie size regardless of number of labels?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am using Chart.js to create pie charts on my site (3 on one page) and I notice that the charts will vary in size depending on the number of labels. What I would like is to fix the pie size to the same for all charts regardless of the number of labels, and have the labels display below. (what is currently happening is that the canvas border defines the outline for everything).